# How do I make my background-image resize to my container

Tags: reactjs, image

So I have a div which has a background-image property with my image inside my object.

```
<div className={containerStyles.image} style = {{ backgroundImage: `url(${img})`}}></div>
```

I need to resize it to my container but it just eats up the whole container.
Here is the CSS code :

```
.image {
border-radius: 4px;
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
background-size:    cover;                     
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center; 
height: 100%;
}
```

And when I try to run the next thing shows up : [image]

How do I make it only take the container size and also not make the text not fit in the container itself?

If anyone wonders here is the card thats inside the container with grid attribute :

```
return ( <div className = {containerStyles.card}>
    <div className={containerStyles.image} style = {{ backgroundImage: `url(${img})`}}></div>
    <p className = {containerStyles.card_name} id = 'based'>{name}</p>
    <p className =  {containerStyles.card_position}>{position}</p>
    <p>{names + ' '}</p>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: So, do you want the text also inside the container, on the image?

Comment: I need both the text and the image to be inside the container, the image basically makes the text overflow.

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue of a live editor like codesandbox, So we can debug? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: "and also not make the text not fit in the container itself?"  Based on your HTML, the text isn't in the container, it's in a different DOM node. You need to put the text inside the div with the background image, not following it.

Comment: What's the style you're giving to .card?